# List<T>.ToArray() not working as expected

Tags: c#, list

I face a problem when I try to use .ToArray() to make a array with deep copy of List.

Here is my test class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Color Color1;
    public MyClass(Color color)
    {
        this.Color1 = color;
    }
}
```

And here is the code which I use to do the ToArray() of List

```
List<MyClass> listColors = new List<MyClass>();
listColors.Add(new MyClass(Color.Blue));
listColors.Add(new MyClass(Color.Green));
listColors.Add(new MyClass(Color.Red));

MyClass[] arrayColors = listColors.ToArray();
arrayColors[2].Color1 = Color.Purple;

Console.WriteLine(arrayColors[2].Color1.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(listColors[2].Color1.ToString());
```

The result:

```
Color [Purple]
Color [Purple]
```

As you see, I made a array MyClass with .ToArray() method then change the element 3rd of this array but I don't know why the List listColors is change too.

I run this sample on windows xp with .NET 2.0.

I try to run this sample on windows 7 and here is the result:

```
Color [Purple]
Color [Red]
```

So I think, this is the problem of .NET framework.

So is there anyway in .NET 2.0 can do the deep copy of List like .NET 4? This is just a test class, in my work, it's bigger.

Thank you very much.

Comment: .ToArray() create a new collection, but does not create new objects.  You are indeed modifying the same object.

Comment: please check your example again. I ran this on .NET 4 and got the first result - I'm explaining in an answer why that is.

Comment: How deep is your copy? (Excuse the Bee Gees pun)

Comment: Obviously you did not run the exact same code to produce this two different results. Do you really think that Microsoft would introduce a breaking change that would break ~99% of all .Net applications ever written?

Comment: @kobigurk Look like it's strange, I ran example again and the result still like my answer.
drch So why it's print out different result when run on different enviroment?
DominicKexel It's just my THINKING!

Comment: Care to provide the actual files?

Answer (score 2):

You are not creating new MyClass objects try this (which gives your expected result):

```
List<MyClass> listColors = new List<MyClass>();
listColors.Add(new MyClass(Color.Blue));
listColors.Add(new MyClass(Color.Green));
listColors.Add(new MyClass(Color.Red));

MyClass[] arrayColors = listColors.ToArray();
arrayColors[2] = new MyClass(Color.Purple);

Console.WriteLine(arrayColors[2].Color1.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(listColors[2].Color1.ToString());
```

In your code you are changing a property of the MyClass object that contains the color Red, the MyClass object is in both the list and array.

Comment: As I said, this just test class, in fact my class is bigger and more complex, so the  arrayColors[2] = new MyClass(Color.Purple); is not good solution. Thank you!

Comment: You can deep copy your arraylist with your own function. This will give you new MyClass objects. I hope it is clear to you why you see `Color [Purple]` twice. How you fix it is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

ToArray() does not perform deep copy, at least not in the sense you expect. It creates an array with the same objects. The best explanation I know about the subject is this : [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1.aspx).

In short, when both of the source and destination lists/arrays are reference types - a shallow copy is performed, meaning that the array contains the same references. Hence, you are changing the original object.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's a few generic methods that work with .Net 2.0. Take the ones you need.

```
public static IList<T> DeepToList<T>(IEnumerable<T> source) where T : IClonable
{
    IList<T> result = new List<T>();
    foreach (T t in source)
    {
        result.Add((T)t.Clone());
    }

    return result;
}

public static T[] DeepToArray<T>(IEnumerable<T> source) where T : IClonable
{
    IList<T> clones =  DeepToList(source);
    T[] result = new T[clones.Count];
    clones.CopyTo(result, 0);
    return result;
}

public static T[] DeepToArray<T>(IList<T> source) where T : IClonable
{
    T[] result = new T[source.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
    {
        result[i] = (T)source[i].Clone();
    }

    return result;
}
```

To use them, `MyClass` would have to implement `IClonable`

```
public class MyClass : IClonable
{
    public Color Color1;
    public MyClass(Color color)
    {
        this.Color1 = color;
    }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return new MyClass(this.Color1);
    }
}
```

so you could do,

```
MyColor[] arrayColors = DeepToArray(listColors)
```

Comment: I'm use the c# 2.0 development so I think can't use this. Thank you.

Comment: @HanTran, I removed any Linq or extensions and I've tested the code targeted against .Net 2.0.